# C# SQL string formatting

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I am new to `.net/C#`. Coming from PHP and some Java, I am finding the new languages interesting and challenging.

I have an issue with a sql string

```
string  query = @"select * from Users where role='member' and
SUBSTRinG(lname, 1, 1) = '"+querystring + "' ORDER BY lname ASC";
```

Which to me, looks fine. however when run my solution and output the query as it is not working, I get this as my output:

```
select * from Users where role=&#39;member&#39; and SUBSTRinG(lname, 1, 1) 
= &#39; O &#39; ORDER BY lname ASC
```

This is output into my Firebug console (the page that uses this query is accessed via AJAX).

Is their a reason my 's are being turned into their code version, ie '&#39'

Thanks

Comment: please show us your code

Comment: this code screams [SQL injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Can you let us know what you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: how do you pass your query ?

Comment: Use SqlParameters instead. That way you don't need to include singlequotes, and you won't run the big risk of allowing SQL Injection. Rule of thumb, never let anything from the user directly into an SqlCommand Text.

Comment: What is the error generated when you run the query against the database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C# you should be using SqlCommand to excute the query, and to prevent sql injection using the parameter collection.

Your query seems fine - The issue might be the way you are running it or the parameters being supplied. Update your question with more details on what you are expecting vs what is happening, include any error messages generated.

Below is a general guideline of how to get data from a sql table to a c# Data Table object.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("YourConnectionString");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"select * from Users where role='member' and
SUBSTRinG(lname, 1, 1) = @query ORDER BY lname ASC");

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@query", querystring);

DataTable resultTable = new DataTable();

try
{
  SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
  da.Fill(resultTable);
} finally {
  if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Closed) conn.Close();
}

Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Matched {0} Rows.", resultTable.Rows.Count));
```

Comment: When I output cmd.CommandText, i get the string as mentioned in the original problem... and so no results are returned

Comment: @nmyster You do not need to output CommandText.  Check if the query should return any values by running it directly against SQL server through SQL Management Studio or something similar.  You should really include your code; we are all guessing here.

Answer (score 1):

### For SQL injection protection:

You can provide escape sequence for single quotes by replacing them with two single quotes `''` so that it will be treated as a single quote inside SQL strings. Otherwise it is considered as a start or end of the string value in SQL.

Replacing single quotes using `&#39;` in .net is also preferred but its better going with two single quotes.